# Prove a language is not regular without pumping lemma

Tags: computability, regular-languages

How can you prove that $L=\{a^n b^{2n} \}$ is not regular without the use of pumping lemma?

Comment: This language is finite hence regular. Did you mean $\{a^nb^{2n}\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1031/755

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to prove a language is not regular:

- the pumping lemma is one of them;
- you can use [closure properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties) of regular languages. For example, if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular then $L = L_1 \cap L_2$ must be regular. That means that if $L$ is not regular, then either $L_1$ or $L_2$ is not regular;
- you can use the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem);
- you can suppose a language is recognized by a DFA, and conclude to a contradiction (the DFA must have at least $n$ states for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it must recognize words not in the language, …)

Comment: In case you were not aware, we have an [elaborate reference posting](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) for questions like this, so you don't need to spend your time answering uninspired questions like the above over and over again. :)

Comment: I realized it with @D.W.'s comment… Thanks for the reminder!